# Looking MS Graph constants to replace magic strings

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using MS Graph SDK to fetch some data for my Blazor Server app. Because I am using more advanced requests, I am using some settings represented by magic strings, like:

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
     new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
     new QueryOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
};
```

or

```
var countElement = (JsonElement) users.AdditionalData["@odata.count"];
```

I would like to remove as many of these magic strings as possible. I was planning on just making a class for holding constants but I wanted to ask if something like that already exists to avoid re-inventing the wheel. I tried looking through MS Graph SDK docs but found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Recently the v5 SDK came out with some [big breaking changes](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md) due to the change of the underlying generator.

By looking at [this section](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#support-for-count-in-request-builders) of the upgrade guide the support for `count` already made it into the code base, but other stuff like the consistencyLevel must still be done with *magic strings*:

```
var count = await graphServiceClient.Users.Count.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
      requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel","eventual"));
```

So just make up your own static class containing the needed const strings in a meaningful way. Here is a spontaneous example:

```
public static class GraphParameters
{
    public const string ConsistencyLevel = "ConsistencyLevel";

    public static class ConsistencyLevelValue
    {
        public const string Eventual = "eventual";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was already going to do that but I wanted to be sure I am not reinventing the wheel. Thanks